# Create a data type similar to OptimizedResult of scipy

Tags: python, scipy

Is there a way to create a datastructure like OptimizeResult. Something different from dict?

Comment: You can look up the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.4/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L82-L138)

Comment: The code says it's a ` Since this class is essentially a subclass of dict
    with attribute accessors,`.